# What is the ^^A in DTX sources?

Tags: documentation, dtx, docstrip

After fleshing out (with my own project) [Joseph Wright's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82992/17423) [lovely model](http://www.texdev.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/demopkg.dtx), I've noticed that the explicit control character `^^A` is used at the end of some lines.  Its use appears similar to that of `%` to ignore trailing spaces, but I don't know why `^^A` would be used instead (if this is indeed its purpose) or why `%` wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: It's the way to refer to invisible ASCII characters. Read dangerous bends (and double-dangerous bend) on page 45 of the *TeXbook*.

Comment: Is that file really mine? I don't recognise it (that doesn't mean it isn't mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - mis-attribution -- It would appear to be Joseph Wright's demo DTX (I'll edit.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle David is not the author of that file, but he's the author of the `ltxdoc.cls` document class which is widely used for making documentation of LaTeX source files.

Comment: @karlkoeller Probably where I made the correlation.  (Am I the only one who thinks it's *awesome* that SE networks make it possible to have this kind of interaction?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `^` has its usual superscript meaning then `^^A` is built-in primitive TeX syntax for the non-printing character control A (that is U+0001) 64 less than `A`. This is just an arbitrary character that Frank chose as being unlikely to be used elsewhere. The important thing about it in this context is that `doc.sty` does

```
\catcode`\^^A=14
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\^^A=14\relax}
```

Catcode 14 is comment (the usual catcode of `%`) This allows you to put comments in the documentation section of a `dtx` file, where `%` is set to catcode 9 so that it is ignored by TeX and does not make a token at all.

Answer (score 6):

In `.dtx` files the sequence `^^A` replaces the standard `%` to introduce comments.

`.dtx` files are usually processed through `doc` and `docstrip` which don't consider `%` a comment.

In fact, when you run latex (or pdflatex) on a such structured `.dtx` file, it is actually evaluated *twice*. The first time, only a small piece of driver code is evaluated. The second time, comments
in the `.dtx` file are evaluated, as if there were no `%` preceding them.

I suggest you to read this very interesting [dtx tutorial](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf) for more information.

Moreover, don't forget to take a look at the original documentation on [`ltxdoc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ltxdoc.pdf), [`doc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/doc.pdf) and [`docstrip`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/docstrip.pdf).

Comment: Exactly how a `.dtx` is read when you send it to  `latex` depends on how it's set up. It's likely that the `.dtx` includes a driver, but that is not required (the design of the `.dtx` format means it's possible to have a very simple file which can be used directly, although this is not so common).

Comment: @JosephWright What you say is right, I was trying to explain how they are designed usually.

Comment: I figured that `^^A` was acting as a comment   flag, I just didn't really know *how* or *why*.  Thanks for the links, though!  Further reading is *always* useful and appreciated :-)